# Geometry nodes in Blender 3.0 : random rotation 180º increment

Tags: transforms, geometry-nodes

I've been searching for a way to rotate instances with a 180º increment. I found a previous solution to this problem

https://www.reddit.com/r/blenderhelp/comments/lwgzsq/random_90_rotation_increments_in_geometry_nodes/

but I don't know how to get it with the new geometry nodes. The most I got is

[image: 90º increment]

but as you can see I only get a simple random rotation not what I need. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Rule of thumb is if there is no ° on the right of the field, you have to use radians. If you don't want to do trigonometry which is understandable, the MATH node mode can be set to "to radians", and then you can input a value in degrees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this node setup:

[image]

The random value give a 0 or 1 with a 50% chance.

shader:

[image]

Comment: So that's the way I have to use Pi. Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 4):

Get a 0 or 1 random output, multiply it by `pi`, and add it to your desired base rotation:

[image]